# Where to store openID-connect's refresh_tokens?

Tags: authentication, jwt, access-token, openid-connect, refresh-token

I'm using an openid-connect authorization provider to authenticate and authorize the users in my web-app. From reading online, I understand that JWT tokens make the app scalable, because then the server doesn't need to keep state for each authenticated client and instead, the access token can be stored in the client and just needs to be validated for each client request.

However, I'm confused about the refresh tokens that I get along with the JWT. Where do I need to store them? Since they seem to be unique for each user (the refresh rest api doesn't need user id), storing them in the server side defeats the scalability purpose. Storing them in the client side also discouraged by the online community.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You didn't describe what you want to achieve - your security model, why you need refresh tokens and what OAuth2 flow you want to use. So it's hard to give you a concrete answer.